# datagridView add rows without data

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

i have datagrid, with 2 columns

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="144" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="300"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="100" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

then i load data from .txt file
{ apple 12
bananas 30 }

```
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var mass = line.Split(' ');
                        dataGrid1.Items.Add(mass);
                    }
```

but i have 2 rows added, without data. (in debug i see: mass[0] - apple, mass[1] - 12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is happening here is that the datagrid is seeing an object[] rather than something it can bind to. Try creating an object to bind to and populate it with the data. This also has the added benefit of making the code a lot clearer to anyone else reading it.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="300" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>

while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var mass = line.Split(' ');
                    var newProduct = new Product
                    {
                        Name = mass[0].ToString(),
                        Price = Convert.ToInt32(mass[1])
                    };

                    dataGrid1.Items.Add(newProduct);

                }


public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try to refresh your datagrid: datagrid1.Items.Refresh()

Comment: My bad...the datagrid columns need to have bindings set to the properties on the Product class, as pointed out by Anka

Answer (score 0):

Use daniellepelley soultion and also add:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="300" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>
```

Comment: Let a comment, don´t put this in an own answer!

Comment: I can not post comments on other users' answers - too low reputation

Comment: Thank you for that, I hadn't noticed the binding was missing on the XAML :D

Comment: thk, I forgot about the binding!)